HTML/CSS: Responsive menu, why won't my main navigation appear at normal (1026px or bigger) screens and only on mobile/tablet size screens?
I'm trying to create a basic responsive site with different screen styles, but my nav menu meant for desktop only appears at mobile screen sizes. I know I'm probably missing something obvious, but what is happening here??


/* -------------------- Mobile Screen ---------------------- */
/* ---------------------- Styles ---------------------- \*/
#mainnav {
display: none !important;
}

        #mobilenav {
            background: #333;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
            width: 100%;
        }
    
        .mobileonly {
        }
    
    
    /* -------------------- Tablet Screen ---------------------- */
        @media all and (min-width:651px) { 
    /* ---------------------- Styles ----------------------- */
        #mainnav {
            display: inherit;
        }
    }

/\* -------------------- Desktop Screen --------------------- */
@media all and (min-width:1026px) {  
/* ---------------------- Styles ----------------------- \*/

        .mobileonly {
            display: none;
        }
    
        #mobilenav {
            display: none;
        }
    
        #mainnav {
            background: #333;
            display: block;
        }
     }

/\* Image styles to make image responsive \*/

img {
max-width:100%;
height:auto;
}

html {
background: #B8B6DD;
min-height: 100vh!important;
}

body {
line-height: 1.45em;
padding-top: 60px;
}

a {
color: #0000EE;
}

a:hover, a:focus {
color: #000000;
}

button {
background-color: #333;
color: #fafafa;
border: none;
}

p {
margin-bottom: 0.75em;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5 {
margin-bottom: 0.75em;
}

h1 {
font-size: 2em;
margin-top: 50px;
}

h2 {
font-size: 1.7em;
}

nav {
font-size: 1.25em;
}

header {
background: rgb(238,174,202);
background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(238,174,202,1) 0%, rgba(148,187,233,1) 100%);
}

main {
margin-top: -20px;
height: 100vh;
}

main, footer {
background: #B8B6DD;
}

table, td, th {
border: 1px solid;
}

table {
width: 50%;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

ul.oi {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
border: none;
}

li.moo {
float: left;
}

ul.mobilelol {
list-style-type: none;
background: #333;
}

li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
background: rgb(238,174,202);
background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(238,174,202,1) 0%, rgba(148,187,233,1) 100%);
}

.active {
background-color: #9BBAE7;
}
   <!-- Do not modify the next three lines. -->

      <!--  Banner content goes here. -->
      
         <br>
         <ul>
            <li>
               <img src="images/a11yman.png" alt="Universal design icon" width="50">         
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="about.html">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            </li>
         </ul>
      
       
         <br>
         <br>
         <h1>Ingrid: IT Accessibility Specialist</h1>

   <a href="#mobilenav">
   <img src="images/hamburger.png" alt="mobile navigation menu" title="Toggle Mobile Navigation Menu">
   </a>

      <!--  Main content goes here. -->
      <br>
      <h2>Service Offerings</h2>
      <ul>
         <li>Digital accessibility audits:
         <ul>
            <li>Web</li>
            <li>Apps (iOS and Android)</li>
            <li>Physical devices (e.g., kiosks)</li>
         </ul></li>
         <li>Accessibility program management consulting</li>
         <li>Policy development</li>
      </ul> 
    
      <h2>Rates</h2>  
      <p><strong>Please note, these rates are approximate and subject to change. Please contact me directly for quotes.</strong></p>
    
      <table>
         <caption>Service Rates</caption>
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th scope="col">Service</th>
               <th scope="col">Rate</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <th scope="row">Digital accessibility audits (web, apps, kiosks)</th>
               <td>$120 per hour</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <th scope="row">Accessibility program management consulting</th>
               <td>Varies</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <th scope="row">Policy development</th>
               <td>$100 per hour</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
    
    
    
      <!--  Footer content goes here -->
      <p>
         Copyright © 2024
      </p>
    
      <nav id="mobilenav">
         <br>
         <ul class="oi">
            <li>
               <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="about.html">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
    
      <!-- <nav id="mobilenav">
         <br>
         <ul class="oi">
            <li class="moo">
               <img style="float: none;" id="logo" class="logo" src="images/a11yman.png" alt="A11y by Ingrid logo" width="50">         
            </li>
            <li class="moo">
               <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="moo">
               <a href="about.html">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="moo">
               <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </nav> -->
    
      <!--<nav id="mobilenav">
         <br>
         <ul class="oi">
            <li>
               <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="about.html">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </nav> -->
    
    
    
      <ul>
         <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
         <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>



I tried using display:none; for the mainnav ID on smaller screens, but again I'm only seeing it on smaller screens and no navigation menus at all on standard desktop/laptop sized screens.

The class .mobileonly doesn't seem to exist in any of your HTML even though you've written styles for it.

For starters: Stop invalidating parts of your CSS, by messing up the comments. /\* ----...--- */ is not a valid comment in CSS, that backslash should not be there.
